# Debug Assertion Failed! / string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am working on string manipulation. I get no warning when compiling, but my program doesn't run. I researched and reviewed the answers to the similar issue but couldn't find the answer. Could you please anybody help on this?

```
Environment
OS: Windows 10 Pro (64 bit)
IDE: Visual Studio Community 2019
```

I get this messages and warning error window when I run the code:

```
*Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: string subscript out of range*
```

[image]

My code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "header.h"


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::string word = "broccoli";
    std::string text = "I sometimes eat broccoli.";

    bleep(word, text);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << text[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**functions.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void bleep(std::string word, std::string &text)
{
    using namespace std;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        int matchCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < word.size(); ++j)
        {
            cout << "j = " << j << endl;
            
            if (text[i + j] == word[j])
            {
                ++matchCount;
                cout << "matchCount = " << matchCount << endl;
            }
        }
        if (matchCount == word.size())
        {
            for (int k = i; k < (i + word.size()); ++k)
            {
                cout << "k = " << k << endl;
                text[k] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
void bleep(std::string word, std::string &text);
```

Comment: `text[i + j]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds, for sufficiently large values of `i` and `j`. E.g. on the last iteration of the outer loop, with `i == text.size()-1`, any value of `j > 1` would take `i+j` out of bounds.

Comment: try to set the upper bound of i in the outer loop to text.size()-word.size()+1 instead of text.size()

Comment: The error message tells you that you used an out-of-range subscript on a string. The next step is for you to determine which string, and what the value of the subscript is. (A debugger would make short work of this. Diagnostics to `std::cerr` would make longer work of this, but still be effective.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your explanation. It makes perfect sense. I corrected my code and it runs! Again thank you so much for your help! : )

Comment: @mradwan Thank you so much for your advice. I corrected my code and it works perfectly. :D !

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for your help! I could figure out how to fix my code. :)

Comment: Click on the "Retry" button, that takes to the error. Also look at the "Call stack" window, that should show step by step where things went wrong.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thank you for your advice!